# Search for types based on their abstract type members

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I have the following type definitions:

```
trait Content
trait Wrapper {
  type ContentType 
}

final case class Foo(param: String) extends Content
final case class Bar(param: String) extends Content

final case class FooWrapper(foo: Foo) extends Wrapper { type ContentType = Foo }
final case class BarWrapper(bar: Bar) extends Wrapper { type ContentType = Bar }
```

Given a content value at runtime, I would like to return it wrapped in its corresponding wrapper type. I tried the following using Shapeless:

```
def fetchWrapper[N, G <: Wrapper](
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[G, N :: HNil],

    // this also compiles, as an alternative to Generics.Aux
    // =:= :G#ValueType =:= N
) = ...
```

It works, but only if I explicitly provide the type parameters: `fetchWrapper[Foo, FooWrapper]`. How do I take advantage of implicit resolution to generalize things so that I can derived the correct wrapper for a given content?

I was thinking of generating an instance of the wrapper using the same derivation technique in the [random number generator](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#case-study-random-value-generator) section of the shapeless book (i.e a typelcass that produces `BarWrapper` if I have an implicit `Bar :: HNil` in scope), but I can't even find the correct wrapper type in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Generic` can easily help with transforming `Wrapper` subtype into `Content` subtype but you want vice versa.

Try a type class

```
trait ContentToWrapper[C <: Content] {
  type Out <: Wrapper { type ContentType = C }
}
object ContentToWrapper {
  implicit val foo: ContentToWrapper[Foo] { type Out = FooWrapper } = null
  implicit val bar: ContentToWrapper[Bar] { type Out = BarWrapper } = null
}

def fetchWrapper[C <: Content](implicit ctw: ContentToWrapper[C]): ctw.Out = ???
```

If you make `Wrapper` sealed you can derive the type class

```
import shapeless.{Coproduct, Generic, HList, Poly1, poly}
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.ToHList
import shapeless.ops.hlist.CollectFirst

object ContentToWrapper {
  implicit def mkContentToWrapper[C <: Content, WC <: Coproduct, WL <: HList](implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[Wrapper, WC],
    toHList: ToHList.Aux[WC, WL], // there is CollectFirst for HList but not for Coproduct
    collect: CollectFirst[WL, WrapperSubtypePoly[C]]
  ): ContentToWrapper[C] { type Out = collect.Out } = null

  trait WrapperSubtypePoly[C] extends Poly1
  object WrapperSubtypePoly {
    implicit def cse[C, A <: Wrapper { type ContentType = C }]: 
      poly.Case1.Aux[WrapperSubtypePoly[C], A, A] = poly.Case1(identity)
  }
}
```

Testing:

```
val w1 = fetchWrapper[Foo]
w1: FooWrapper
val w2 = fetchWrapper[Bar]
w2: BarWrapper
```

Comment: Thanks. `ToList` and `CollectFirst` are what I was looking for.